# Print Nested Dictionary Keys and values in a tabular format

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, nested

I would like to print my nested dictionary into a tabular format which would somehow look like this:

```
**ID**      **Count**    **Time**   **OutCount**  **OutTime**

  262          725        15:29          725         15:29
```

and so on .....

My nested dictionary is:

```
{'262': {'count': 725,'time': '15:29','outcount': 725,'outtime': '15:29'},
'343': {'count': 699,'time': '15:29','outcount': 699,'outtime': '15:29'},
'809': {'count': 695,'time': '15:29','outcount': 695,'outtime': '15:29'}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`pd.DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html)

```py
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
     count   time  outcount outtime
262    725  15:29       725   15:29
343    699  15:29       699   15:29
809    695  15:29       695   15:29
```

or with [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

```py
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').reset_index()
  index  count   time  outcount outtime
0   262    725  15:29       725   15:29
1   343    699  15:29       699   15:29
2   809    695  15:29       695   15:29
```